# ¿Cómo obtener un contenido en específico de una página que se encuentra etiquetas <ul><li> anidadas?

Tags: php, dom

Estoy tratando de leer el contenido HTML de una página cargada mediante URL usando `file_get_contents`.

Lo que me interesa de la página es sacar el contenido organizado en un array por meses, días y fiesta, algo así:

```
array (
        "Enero"  => array(1 => "Año Nuevo", 2=>"Epifanía del Señor"),
        "Febrero"=> array(28=> "Día de Andalucía"),
        "Etc..."
     )
```

A pesar de que en la URL se ve el contenido organizado por meses, anidado entre varios `div`, y luego combinaciones de `ul` y de `li`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo dar con el contenido ordenado por meses para crear mi array.

Hasta ahora tengo este código:

```
$url='http://www.mitramiss.gob.es/es/informacion/calendarios/fiestas2018/comunidades/contenidos/calendariolab_and.htm';
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$doc=$dom->loadHTML($page);
$ul = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
foreach ($ul as $v) {
    var_dump($v->nodeValue);                    
}
```

El `var_dump` muestra todos los `nodeValue`, y el que me interesa lo muestra así:

> string(425) "Enero.Día  1. Año NuevoDía 6. Epifanía del Señor.Febrero.
>   Día 28. Día de Andalucía.Marzo Día 29 . Jueves Santo.Día 30. Viernes
>   Santo.Mayo. Día 1. Fiesta del Trabajo.Agosto. Día 15. Asunción de la
>   Virgen.Octubre. Día 12. Fiesta Nacional de España.Noviembre. Día 1.
>   Todos los Santos.Diciembre. Día 6. Día de la Constitución Española.Día
>   8. La Inmaculada Concepción.Día 25. Natividad del Señor."

Se podría trabajar arduamente esa cadena para obtener el array que quiero, pero viendo que en el DOM original los datos están organizados por meses, quisiera encontrar una forma de traer la información por meses para construir mi array. ¿Conocen alguna forma de alcanzar los datos allí donde están por meses?

La idea es encontrar los días por cualquier mes del año de Enero a Diciembre. El código es para sacar los festivos de varias URLs donde las mismas podrán tener o no un determinado mes del año.

Answer (score 0):

Te lo pongo como respuesta, ya que no me deja comentartelo... pero... has probado la extensión php simple_html_dom?

sería así:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$url = "http://www.mitramiss.gob.es/es/informacion/calendarios/fiestas2018/comunidades/contenidos/calendariolab_and.htm"; 
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url); 
    $post = $html->find('div[class=caja]', 0)->plaintext;
```

De esta manera devuelve solo las fechas que quieres, y no será tan arduo trabajar ese string